# How to append AND clause to a query in oracle store procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have two tables named, `CUSTOMER` and `PRODUCT`. I tried to append a part to the running query. I tried with the following,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CUSTOMERS(
availability      IN PRODUCT.AVAILABILITY%TYPE,
customer_title    IN CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TITLE%TYPE,
from_date         IN VARCHAR2,
to_date           IN VARCHAR2,
customer_category IN VARCHAR2,
customers          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN

OPEN customers FOR
SELECT
  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE
FROM CUSTOMER CUSTOMER INNER JOIN PRODUCT PRODUCT ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE = PRODUCT.CUSTOMER_CODE
WHERE AVAILABILITY = GET_CUSTOMERS.availability AND
      (CUSTOMER.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(GET_CUSTOMERS.from_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
      AND TO_DATE(GET_CUSTOMERS.to_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss'))
      AND GET_CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_category
      AND (PRODUCT.PRODUCT_SKU_ID = 'b36e3e27-61d6-4080-9383-d5397110698d')
      AND (LOWER(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TITLE) LIKE LOWER('%' || GET_CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_title || '%'))
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE;
END;
/
```

String part that I tried to append is **GET_CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_category**

I got the following error.

```
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.GET_CUSTOMERS is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: First, never create objects in the `system` (or `sys`) schema.  Those schemas are special.  Second, what error do you get when you create the procedure?  You appear to be posting the error that you get when you try to execute the procedure not the error that you get trying to call the procedure.  Finally, what do you want `and get_customers.customer_category` to do?  Perhaps you want to compare that to a `category` column in the `customer` table?

Comment: `and get_customers.customer_category` is the binary operation which I passed from programme.

Comment: I got `Error(19,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`